# Curves and line for coordinate geometry

Tags: geometry

The curve $y = x^2$ lies above the line $$y = px - q^2$$ for $-2 < p < 2$. Find the value(s) of constant $q$.

I have tried equating the both equations and substituting $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ into it.

x^2$ - px = -q^2$

-(x^2$ - px) = q^2$

-x(x - p) = q^2$

-2(2 - p) = q^2$

2p - 4 = q^2$

q = +-sqrt(2p -4)

Comment: Do the line and the curve intersect? Because if you take $q$ to be large enough, it clearly works

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=x^2$ lies above the line, we have,
$$x^2\gt px-q^2 \forall x\in\mathbb R$$
$$x^2-px+q^2\gt0\forall x\in\mathbb R$$
Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, this is satisfied if the discriminant is negative, which would result in the graph of this curve completely lying above the $x$-axis.
$$D=p^2-4q^2\lt0$$
$$p^2\lt4q^2$$
We have, $$p^2\lt4$$
Thus,
$$4\le4q^2$$
$$q^2\ge1$$
$$q\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For all $p\in(-2,2)$, you need

$$x^2>px-q^2\iff x^2-px+q^2>0$$

for all $x$.

Comment: Hi, can I ask how do you know if the equation is >0, =0 or <0. 

And do I need to use the b^2$ - 4ac (discriminant) ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the discriminant. Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, the quadratic is $U$-shaped, and so will be positive everywhere if it has no real roots, i.e. if the discriminant is negative.